# How does "apply" work in an companion object (with Trait) in Scala?

Tags: scala, traits

Source: Functional Programming in Scala MEAP v10

In the below pasted code

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {
  def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
    case Nil => 0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs)
 }
  def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)
  }
  def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] = {

    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
  val example = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
}
```

The Cons object is constructed presumably by the apply(), but the type signatures are different, how does scala end up assembling the Cons instance.

also while there is no un-apply, though the below code works absolutely fine, disassembling the List into Cons(head, tail)

```
object a{
  val x = List(1,2,3,4,5) match {
    case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
    case Nil => 42
    case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
    case Cons(h, t) => h + List.sum(t)
    case _ => 101
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A `Cons` instance is always constructed by `Cons`' constructor. You can call it directly:

```
val myList = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, Nil)) // list containing the elements 1 and 2
```

The `apply` method on the companion object is a factory method that allows you to construct a list with a nicer syntax :

```
val myList = List(1, 2) // expanded to List.apply(1, 2) by the compiler ; same result as above
```

There is no reason why they would need to have the same type signature, since they don't need to be called the same way.

As for why you can use pattern-matching without defining a `unapply` method : that's because you defined `Nil` and `Cons` as case classes/objects. A case class gets a number of functionalities for free (generated by the compiler), including the `unapply` method (but also `equals`, `hashcode` and `toString` for instance).

---

Edit: Some precisions based on the comments:

**Constructors in Scala:**
In Scala, each class has a default constructor, whose parameters are automatically available as fields in the class - so the default constructor doesn't need to have its own method body. For instance, the following Scala classes:

```
class Foo1(bar: Int)
class Foo2(val bar: Int)
```

Are roughly equivalent to the following Java classes:

```
public class Foo1 {
    public Foo1(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    private int bar;
}

public class Foo2 {
    public Foo2(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    private int bar;
    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

**Polymorphism:**
`Nil` and `Cons` both extend `List`. This means that *a `Cons` is a kind of `List`*. So if you create an instance of `Cons` with `val myList = new Cons(1, Nil)`, `myList` is an object of type `Cons`... But it's also:

- of type `List`
- of type `AnyRef`, because it's the root class of all reference types. All classes in Scala extend `AnyRef` by default, so `List` extends `AnyRef` (because it doesn't have an explicit `extends` clause).
- of type `Any`, which is the root of all Scala types.

The following code uses your `List`/`Cons`/`Nil` implementations:

```
val myList = List(1, 2, 3)
  // Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))) => result of the toString method generated by the compiler because it's a case class
myList.getClass.getName
  // Cons   => this is the concrete type of myList
myList.isInstanceOf[Cons[_]]
  // true   => myList is a Cons
myList.isInstanceOf[Nil.type]
  // false
myList.isInstanceOf[List[_]]
  // true   => but it's also a kind of List
val foo: List[Int] = myList
  //        => this is allowed
myList.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]
  // true
myList.isInstanceOf[Any]
  // true

val anotherList = List()
  // Nil
anotherList.getClass.getName
  // Nil$   => the name is mangled with a $ sign to differentiate the 'object Nil' in case you also declare a 'class Nil'
anotherList.isInstanceOf[List[_]]
  // true
```

Comment: But how does scala knows it has to create a list with (head , tail) when that implementation is down there only in apply method, I do accept on the mentions about syntactic sugar of variadic params, and unapply method of case class though.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question? Calling `MyObject.apply(param)` when you write `MyObject(param)` is just a language convention implemented in the compiler. The `apply` method takes a vararg parameter, represented by a `Seq` in Scala (rather than an array like in Java) - so the parameter `as: A*` is used like a parameter `as: Seq[A]`. The code in the `apply` method then just uses this `Seq`'s public methods to determine what's inside and call the correct constructor; if it constructs a `Cons`, `apply` has to call itself recursively to construct the tail of the `Cons`.

Comment: Sorry if was not clear, calling `Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))` will return me a `List(1, 2, 3, Nil)`, how does this happen, I assumed apply method happens to do the trick of constructing an instance of List and return, but left confused when I saw the difference in the type signature

Comment: More over `case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]` signature doesn't specify a body of the constructor, so how does Scala create the List instance. _Pardon my novice level_

Comment: We were all novices at some point, don't worry. :-) I will edit my answer, there's not enough space in the comments.